# extract 3 biggest cores using networkx library

Tags: python, networkx

could you tell me how can i extract 3 biggest cores from graph using networkx? I know that i can extract main core in this way:

```
networkx.k_core(G)
```

but how find 3 biggest cores?
thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your question.  It's a little unclear at the moment what you want.  The easiest way to clarify it is to provide a simple example of an input graph and the result you want.

Comment: Is this what you're asking: Take a given number `k`.  If I delete all nodes of degree less than `k` and repeat this process until the remaining graph has all nodes with degree at least `k`, how do I find the three largest components of this graph?  This is my best guess for what you might mean.  I'm unclear about what a "biggest" core is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
core_number(G)
```

If you check the definition, the core number of a node is the largest value k of a k-core containing that node. Now all you have to do is to find the top 3 core numbers and then call

```
k_core(G, k)
```

for each k in top 3 core numbers to get the top 3 k-core subgraphs.

Comment: thanks for your help, i didn't know that such function exist